# Maximum Mobility Speed in OMNET++

Tags: performance, omnet++, mobility

I am trying to implement AD HOC wireless project with mobility I wanted to know the maximum mobility speed of a node during a simulation in omnet++?

Answer (score 0):

The mobility model uses non-relativistic coordinate transformations so there is no inherent speed limit for the objects.

(Obviously the speed value itself is limited by the double type, so it has a maximum value of 1.8 × 10^308, but I guess that is not the information you are after.)